# how to download a file from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, download

I want to download file from my uploads table using the attribute sub_name,
need help. I have this code of two `PHP` file one shows the files other downloads it but it's not working.

The uplaods table include sub_name, upload_name, file_content (which is actually the uploaded file) .

My code (the table from which data is sent to be downloaded is):

```
<?php
    include_once("functions.php");
    $query="SELECT * from uploads";
    $rs = execute_query($query);
?>

<form  action="s_downfinl.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="groove" cellpadding="15px">
<tr>
<td>Subject Name</td>
<td>upload name</td>
<td>Download</td>
</tr>
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
        echo "<tr><td>";

        echo $row['sub_name']."</td><td>";  
        echo $row['upload_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='s_downfinl.php?nama=".$file."'>download</a></td>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
?>
</form>
```

**downlaod.php**

```
    <?php
include_once"functions.php()";

$query = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE sub_name = $sub_name";
$rs = execute_query($query);
$name= $_GET['nama'];
download($name);

function download($name){
$file = $nama_fail;

if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}
}
?>
```

**fuctions.php (for database connection)**

```
<?php
function execute_query($query){
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("ascs",$connection);
$result_set = mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($connection);
return $result_set;
}
?>
```

Comment: Is `WHERE sub_name = $sub_name` <= that a string by any chance?

Comment: `$nama_fail` is not defined

Comment: Plus, not querying at all, just defining it.

Comment: please edit question, dcode in comments is hard to read

Comment: @dagon  i have edited i hope it is easy to understand now

Comment: @fred-ii- i want to download the file using sub_name from the table :

Comment: you dont run the query.

Comment: @Dagon [*I said that...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683421/how-to-download-a-file-from-database#comment45659723_28683421)

Comment: @Fred-ii- i know, but i dont think it sank in

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE sub_name = $sub_name";` this is nver run, its just a string in a variable

Comment: @dagon $rs = execute_query($query);i added this but its still not working

Comment: is `execute_query` a function you have defined?

Comment: @Dagon yes i have this functions.php n which databse connection is defined plus execute query func which execute the queries... it works fine coz i use it like aall the time

Comment: What's this => `include_once"functions.php()";` ? why the `()`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is a php file i use for database connection open and close.. i will add it in my question plz have a look of it

Comment: a filename passed/used as a function, ok.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Also use `var_dump();` to see what's passing through or not. *Gotta run, supper time!*

Comment: Please check this link:-http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/07/file-download-coding-using-php-and-mysql.html